# lvalue returned with pointer in C

Tags: c

I tried to execute the following piece of code,

```
int val=10;
printf("%d",++val++);
```

As expected I got the following error message, "`lvalue required as increment operand`". But when I made the following change the program was working fine.

```
int val=10;
int *ptr=&val;
printf("%d",++*ptr++);
```

The program gave an output of **11**. The output value was not surprising.

But the whole construct `++*ptr++` being an `lvalue` and not an `rvalue` was confusing.

I printed the contents of `ptr` before and after as follows,

```
printf("%u\n",ptr);
printf("%d",++*ptr++);
printf("\n%d\n",ptr);
```

**2293532** and **2293536** were the addresses printed on screen. So clearly `ptr` has incremented and pointer addition is involved.

The output makes sense except for the fact that `*ptr` retrieves the content of the variable whose address is stored in `ptr` which is **10** and `++*ptr` increments it to **11**. This definitely is an `rvalue`. But the post increment (`++`) has been bound to `ptr` I believe. Why so? What rules govern such bindings in C?

Comment: The undefined behavior in this is in the type of the arguments to `printf()` not matching the conversion-specifier.

Comment: Undefined behaviour

Comment: In Code::Blocks there were no warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observation is correct, i.e. prefix `++` is applied to the value the pointer points to (int), while the postfix `++` is applied to the pointer itself.

This is due to fact that postfix `++` operator [has higher priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `*` and therefore takes precedence. So first `ptr` is incremented and its original value is returned, then this pointer is dereferenced and the `int` value it points to is incremented and returned by the expression. The prefix `++` is applied after `*` because of its order and dependency in the code, and they have equal priority anyway.

PS: The correct formatter to print pointer is "%p".

Comment: "it cannot be reorganized due to its chaining" Hmm, "chaining?". What does this mean? The reason they can't get get re-organized is the rvalue caused by this specific expression. `*++p` would otherwise be fine.

Comment: @Lundin : I admit the wording wasn't very clear and changed it. I meant the dependency of one operator on the another expression. Otherwise sure, they can be written in any order, my point was that even if the priority is different the order actually would matter here.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%d",++val++);
```

Postfix ++ has higher operator precedence than prefix ++, therefore `val++` is evaluated first. The result of the operation is a *rvalue* - it can't be modified. But the prefix ++ operator expects the operand to be an *lvalue* (modifiable), so the expression isn't valid.

```
printf("%d",++*ptr++);
```

Here the operator precedence is such that postfix ++ still has highest precedence. `ptr++` will get evaluated first, which means that pointer arithmetic is applied to increase the address of `ptr` by one element. The increment happens after `ptr` has been evaluated.

Prefix ++ and unary * have the same precedence, but operator associativity for this group of operators is right-to-left, meaning that *, being most to the right, gets evaluated first. Unlike the ++ operators, the unary * doesn't require a lvalue operand. It is sufficient that it gets a pointer type operand, which it does in this case.

As a special case, the unary * operator, when applied to a pointer-to-object, gives a result which is a lvalue. Therfore the prefix ++ now work, where it failed in the previous expression. It will however not increment the pointer, but the pointed-at contents: integer addition by 1.

Please note that you should never mix the ++ operators with other operators, since a ++ operation involves a *side effect*. Doing so is bad practice and might invoke undefined behavior bugs. [See this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior).